# Divergence Theorem Questions Assistance (elliptical parabolid?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, divergence-theorem

Compute the flux of water through parabolic cylinder $S:y=x^2$, from $0\le x\le 2$, $0\le z\le 3$, if the velocity vector is $F(x,y,z)=3z^2i+6j+6xzk$.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgAmf.jpg)
Here's my set up right now, it doesn't look right... my main confusion is how to set up the bound such that only the bounds of x and z stated are included

Comment: Hi, I've added a picture. Any assistance as how to correctly set up the bounds would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize a parabolic cylinder was something entirely different from a paraboloid

Answer (score 1):

Given the vector field $\mathbf{F} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ of law:

$$
\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = \left(3z^2,\,6,\,6xz\right)
$$

and given the surface $\mathbf{r} : [0,2]\times[0,3] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ of law:

$$
\mathbf{r}(u,v) = (u,\,u^2,\,v)
$$

with support $\Sigma$, by *definition* the flux of $\mathbf{F}$ through $\Sigma$ is equal to:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi_{\Sigma}(\mathbf{F}) 
& := \iint\limits_{\Sigma} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}_{\Sigma}\,\text{d}S \\
& = \iint\limits_{[0,2]\times[0,3]} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u,v))\cdot\left(\mathbf{r}_u(u,v) \land \mathbf{r}_v(u,v)\right)\text{d}u\,\text{d}v \\
& = \iint\limits_{[0,2]\times[0,3]} \left(3v^2,\,6,\,6uv\right)\cdot\left(2u,\,-1,\,0\right)\text{d}u\,\text{d}v \\
& = \int_0^2 \text{d}u \int_0^3 6\left(u\,v^2-1\right)\text{d}v \\
& = \int_0^2 18\,(3\,u-1)\,\text{d}u \\
& = 72\,.
\end{aligned}
$$

In particular, if $\mathbf{F}$ is the velocity field of a fluid, then $\Phi$ is the flow rate through $\Sigma$:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

where, being an open surface, the application of the *divergence theorem* is awkward.